# Google app engine suas cookies not expiring

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies

When using [suas](https://github.com/aht/suas) in GAE and setting the flash_msg, for some reason the cookie does not expire. The symptom is that no mater how many times I refresh the page the flash message is always there. When I debugged with chrome I can see that the expiration the flash_msg cookies was set to session. Even more troubling I found that all cookies expiry are set to session. Any idea? The only change I made to the SUAS code was removing the error raising in
    def __ParseString(self, str, patt=Cookie._CookiePattern):

Also note that the flash_msg cookie has a domain other then "/".

Update:
All the variables being session-ed are because they were meant to. SUAS has a persist variable that sets if the cookies will be session cookies or persist. As a work around for the flash messages I use the jQuery plug in for cookies and just delete the guys after I display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cookies do not expire on page load. They expire when the browser closes. What you need to do is at every page load, if flash is in session, display it and then force remove it from the session (on the server side).

Comment: So this would be done client side? SUAS sets the max-age to 0 after a flash message is handled. However the expired cookie keeps coming back from the client. Also isn't it strange that all cookies are session variables? This would include user and SID which are used to remember log in. I would expect by setting the max-age they would expire when expected.

Comment: No, I meant in your request handler you should remove the flash from the session and it will automatically be removed from the cookie. My full answer to the problem would be to stop using SUAS and start using gae-sessions as it is much nicer.